# Pyqt5 Two QButton Drag and Drop

Tags: python, pyqt5

There are two buttons on the window called Button1 and Button2. In the code below, I can move it by right-clicking the button named Button1. Button1 moves again when I want to right-click and drag Button2. But I can't move Button2 with the code below. I want to move which one of these two buttons right click.How can I do that?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag
import sys

class Button(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, title, parent):
        super().__init__(title, parent)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() != Qt.RightButton:
            return
        mimeData = QMimeData()
        drag = QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setHotSpot(e.pos() - self.rect().topLeft())
        dropAction = drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        super().mousePressEvent(e)
        if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            print('press')

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.button1 = Button('Button1', self)
        self.button1.setFixedSize(100,100)
        self.button1.move(0, 0)

        self.button2 = Button('Button2', self)
        self.button2.move(0, 110)
        self.setWindowTitle('Click or Move')
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 400)


    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        position = e.pos()
        print(position)
        self.button1.move(position)
        e.setDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        e.accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: In quick glance I see you only have self.button1.move(position) in dropEvent. I think you should add button2 and a check to see which one should move.

Comment: How can I check which button is right clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to subclass a button to move it, and you certainly shouldn't use drag&drop if you're going to move the object within the same parent.

Also, if you're going to check only movements that happen while the right button is pressed, you should *always* call the base implementation for the other situations (other buttons, or no button, in case [`mouseTracking`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop) is enabled; it's not usually the case with push buttons, but that's not the point).

Install an event filter on the buttons, and track the following events:

- QEvent.MouseButtonPress: if the button is the right one, set a variable for the current moving widget and another one with the current mouse position (let's say, startPosition)
- QEvent.MouseMove: if a current moving widget exists, move it using the formula `newPosition = currentPosition + eventPosition - startPosition`
- QEvent.MouseButtonRelease: clear the current moving widget

```
class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

        self.movingButton = None

    def initUI(self):

        self.button1 = QPushButton('Button1', self)
        self.button1.setFixedSize(100,100)
        # no need for this, every new widget is always placed at (0, 0)
        # self.button1.move(0, 0)
        self.button1.installEventFilter(self)

        self.button2 = QPushButton('Button2', self)
        self.button2.move(0, 110)
        self.button2.installEventFilter(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Click or Move')
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 400)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source in (self.button1, self.button2):
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress and event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
                self.movingButton = source
                self.startPos = event.pos()
            # uncomment the following lines if you want to move the button while
            # moving the mouse
            # elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseMove and self.movingButton:
            #     self.movingButton.move(source.pos() + event.pos() - self.startPos)
            elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease and self.movingButton:
                self.movingButton.move(source.pos() + event.pos() - self.startPos)
                self.movingButton = None
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

Comment: is it possible to use this code to drag an drop a QLabel?

Comment: @RuhiUlusoy just add the eventfilter to that label and check if it is equal to the `source` in the `eventFilter()` function as I did with the buttons.

Comment: Yes, it also worked for Qlabel. Last question. How can I find out the coordinates of the last positions of an object after its motion?

Comment: @RuhiUlusoy You can only know the previous position within a QMoveEvent (override `moveEvent()` in a subclass or filter the `QtCore.QEvent.Move` event type), which is generated every time `move()` or `setGeometry()` is called on a widget.